# Top Questions history

Tags: feature-request, top-questions

Is there a way to view the history of [Top Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=week) on a week-by-week (and/or month-by-month) basis?

I enjoy looking through the weekly top questions and would love to be able to go back in time with it. Am I able to find out what the top questions were 10 weeks ago, for example?

Sure, I could just [sort all questions by votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions), but this would push a lot of really good questions way down that list - even questions on page 100 have over 130 upvotes, and past that point you get to a lot of questions with answers which may no longer be relevant at all.

Comment: This can be done via the Data-Explorer. Alternatively, you use the search to filter questions by  minimum # of votes. And then sort by newest.

Answer (score 1):

They are currently provided in the [moderator-tools panel](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) to 10k+ users(and moderators)

Link to the panel is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=stats). A screenshot is shown below:

[image]

Comment: This isn't quite the same. The 30d for instance is the top questions when measured over the last 30 days rather than the top questions 30 days ago.